# how to mount a github repository as the current directory folder in google colab?

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory, mount

I am currently loading the images from my Google Drive.

But the issue is, those images are in my drive and when I share my colab notebook to others, they can't run it since it requires my authentication code to access the Drive images.

So I thought if I uploaded the data folder in a Github repository & made that repo as public will allow anyone to fetch the data (in my case images folder). Thus no authentication required to run the colab code.

I have no idea how to mount the directory to a Github repo as Google Drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/') # this will set my  google drive folder as the notebook directory.
```

Is it possible to do a similar mounting to a github repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the repository directly like this by running git in a code cell.

```
!git clone https://github.com/yourusername/yourpublicrepo.git
```

This will create a folder called `yourpublicrepo`.

Comment: Wow ! ,Thanks a lot , i tried and succesful

Comment: I don't want to clone repo in disk. I want to mount a repo as disk over network.There is any solution?